# Interrogating word under cursor for spelling highlighting in vim

Tags: vim

I've recently discovered the built-in spell checking of Vim. I noticed in the documentation that there were several classes of highlighted words that are revealed by activating spell checking (a la `:setlocal spell spelllang=en_us`). These different classes show me different kinds of spelling errors, but it's not always clear to me which kind of error I've made just based on the color.

I know that I can look at different spelling suggestions for the word using `z=` with my cursor over it, but I'd really like a similar command that just tells me what type of spelling error I've made.

I also know that I could look at the list of different highlighting classes using `:hi`, but that's rather unwieldy. I'd like to have a quick way of looking up the name of the class from the `:hi` table that is being applied to the text under the cursor.

The closest I've gotten is `:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name")`, which gives me the syntactic context under the cursor. This doesn't actually tell me anything about spelling in any of the contexts I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to query the current word's type of spell error. Because I frequently forget which highlighting means what, I have defined this command to aid my memory:

```
function! s:SpellLegend()
    for [l:group, l:explanation] in [
    \   ['SpellBad', 'word not recognized'],
    \   ['SpellCap', 'word not capitalized'],
    \   ['SpellRare', 'rare word'],
    \   ['SpellLocal', 'wrong spelling for selected region']
    \]
        echo ''
        echon l:group . "\t"
        execute 'echohl' l:group
        echon 'xxx'
        echohl None
        echon "\t" . l:explanation
    endfor
endfunction
command! -bar SpellLegend call s:SpellLegend()
```

Comment: Great answer! This is just the sort of thing I was looking for.

Can I ask why you make the command using `command! -bar`? I understand that this makes the command pipeable, but I'm not sure I understand the motivation behind doing that.

Comment: As the command doesn't take any arguments, it doesn't hurt to allow use in a command sequence. It's a minor touch, really. Oh, and if you found this useful, please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the outlined arrow next to it.

Comment: Is it more appropriate to accept an answer that was helpful but doesn't fully answer the question, or hold out for the question to be more fully answered later? I appreciate your answer very much and it satisfies my needs, but I'm not sure it answers my question per se.

Comment: Your call, but it's unlikely to get additional answers (soon), and you can always change your mind and un-accept this, in case a better answer comes along.